# Grab two users ID and join them into another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm so new to SQL Server database and working on recent project. I have two tables `Users` and `Friends`. `Users` has all names and IDs and other additional columns. `Friends` table has `firstuserID`, `SecondUserID` and `Friendstatus` columns and doesn't have the names of the users.

I have add the IDS manually to friends table and I want to show their status based on their names. The query I made

```
    @username nvarchar(50),
    @friendname nvarchar(50)
AS
   SELECT * 
   FROM Friends 
   WHERE ID IN 
       (SELECT ID as ID 
        FROM Users 
        WHERE UserName = @usernameID 
        UNION
        SELECT ID as MyID 
        FROM Users 
        WHERE UserName = @friendnameID)
```

I know for sure my query is wrong. Can you please give me a hint or help me out.

Comment: please add expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @username nvarchar(50),
    @friendname nvarchar(50)
AS
   SELECT * 
   FROM Friends 
   WHERE ID IN 
       (SELECT ID 
        FROM Users 
        WHERE UserName IN(@username,@friendname) 
         )
```

Comment: @Muterb :- Is this query really work I assume that the Id column in Friends table is PK of friends table and in the above query its seems like a  foreign key of User table ?